# Terraform MalformedXML: The XML you provided was not well-formed for aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I really stuck today on the following error:

> MalformedXML: The XML you provided was not well-formed

when applying `aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration` via Terraform using hashicorp/aws v4.38.0.
I wanted to set a rule that would expire files after 365 days with file size greater than 0 bytes for a `my_prefix` prefix so the definition of the resource looks like that:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "my-bucket-lifecycle-configuration" {
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_versioning.my-bucket-versioning]

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.id

  rule {
    id = "my_prefix_current_version_config"

    filter {
      and {
        prefix = "my_prefix/"
        object_size_greater_than = 0
      }
    }

    expiration {
      days = 365
    }

    status = "Enabled"
  }

}
```

Anyone has idea what's wrong with the above definition? :nerd_face:
Documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration

Remark: the following definition can be applied without problem (no `and` block):

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "my-bucket-lifecycle-configuration" {
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_versioning.my-bucket-versioning]

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.id

  rule {
    id = "my_prefix_current_version_config"

    filter {
      prefix = "my_prefix/"
    }

    expiration {
      days = 365
    }

    status = "Enabled"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration#specifying-a-filter-based-on-object-size-range-and-prefix), you have to specify both the object **size range** (which I guess mean, you have to specify both `object_size_greater_than` and `object_size_less_than`) and **prefix**, for example:

```
filter {
  and {
    prefix                   = "my_prefix/"
    object_size_greater_than = 0
    object_size_less_than    = 500
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually I don't need to have both `object_size_greater_than` and `object_size_less_than` as apply went thru when I assigned `object_size_greater_than = 1` so I think it's some kind of error in terraform / AWS API..

Comment: I agree with you, It is not clear enough in the documentation, I answered based on what I see in the doc ;)